# Could not load type "genemu_jqueryautocomplete_text": class does not exist

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and SHFormBundle. When I want to create form with autocomplete field I get error:

```
Could not load type "genemu_jqueryautocomplete_text": class does not exist.
```

My code:

```
$builder
        ->add('code', 'genemu_jqueryautocomplete_text', [
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true,
            'route_name' => 'pso_product_fast_code_ajax_tyre',
            'configs' => [
                'minLength' => 2,
            ],
        ]);
```

Some suggestion what is wrong?

Comment: Seems to require https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle - is that installed?

Comment: If GenemuBundle is installed, you should try to call it with its full qualified name, not its shortname...

Comment: GenemuBundle is not installed because is incompatible with my project dependencies. I have installed SHFormBundle.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is that you need to use an fqcn as the form type but there is no such class since the `genemu_jqueryautocomplete_text` is defined via Dependency Injection (without a class) see https://github.com/symfony-hackers/SHFormBundle/blob/4c150e4e739ee1dad0dfe3ddf359d19965c6ff70/DependencyInjection/SHFormExtension.php#L215-L218

```
$serviceId = 'genemu.form.jquery.type.autocomplete';
$textDef = new DefinitionDecorator($serviceId);
$textDef->addArgument('text')->addTag('form.type', array('alias' => 'genemu_jqueryautocomplete_text'));
$container->setDefinition($serviceId . '.text', $textDef);
```

I've fixed it by creating proper classes for the autocomplete form types. This can be found at https://github.com/storefront-bvba/SHFormBundle. Currently the package isn't on packagist but one can install it by using [vcs as package source](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)